# Visual Studio Code Analysis doesn´t refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I´m using code analysis in visual studio 2013 to improve my code qualtity. One suggestion of codeanlysis is to rename the .dll I´ve coded from LoginLib.dll to LogOnLib.dll. I already changed that, but that warining is still displayed. I cleand and rebuilded the solution, I closed and opened visual studio, I even restartet my computer but the warning still remains. I also changed the assemblytitle and the assemblyproduct in the AssemblyInfo. What else can I do?

Warining:

[image]

Dll name:

[image]

AssemblyInfo:

[image]

Comment: Did you change the file name under Project Properties?

Comment: No I didn´t, don´t know why I forgot that. I changed it now and as a consequence I of cause had to change the usings and namespaces of the classes inside the .dll. Thank you, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file name under Project Properties.